# I am not able to switch on -off my ASUS ROG G531D Backlite

Tags: keyboard, asus, brightness

I am not able to switch ON-Off my backlit or neither able to change it colour and brightness.
please help me with solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to need to provide more info for your particular situation.  In my situation I have a dual boot system that started life as a Windows 10 machine.  Before I could set up the dual boot I went into the Windows 10 set up provided by Asus as this contained the "eSupport" drive which contained all the drivers provided for by Asus.  I copied this to my oneDrive then proceeded to the set the dual boot system.  Once Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 were installed I went into Windows 10 and installed the drivers from "eSupport".  I also had to download the AuraService from Asus which is the driver to control the keyboard backlighting.

I have an Asus G703GS.

I don't think the Asus drivers run on Linux, but I could be wrong.

That was my situation, you'll probably have to provide more for your situation.